# Where I should install GRUB bootloader, and chainloading bootloader?

Tags: installation, grub2, dual-boot, bootloader, ubuntu-studio

I wanted to install Ubuntu Studio, and I'm confused where I should install GRUB. I wanted to chainload bootloader (because I want to dual-boot) and keeps Windows Bootloader, because I'm using EasyBCD.

Here is the list of my partitions:

```
/dev/sda          (HD 500 GB)
 /dev/sda1 132 GB (Windows 8 bootloader)
 /dev/sda2 141 GB (NTFS-formatted partition for Windows 8)
 /dev/sda3 151 GB (NTFS-formatted partition for Windows 8)
 /dev/sda4        (Extended Partition)
  /dev/sda5  11 GB (FAT32)
  /dev/sda6  25 GB (Ubuntu) (mount: /) ##planned##
  /dev/sda7   5 GB (Home Folder (/home))
  /dev/sda8   1 GB (swap memory) ##planned##
```

Which partition should I choose to install GRUB? I'm new to Linux.

Thanks for answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can install that on every partition that you want.(i.e. you can install it on multi partitions by issue grub-install )
. Because all of the installed partitions point to same thing.
But please take note that you cannot install it on /boot partition since it is not a block device.).
Please be in touch with me by farshidzamanirad@gmail.com
regards
Farshid